# Analyzing $\overline{A}\setminus \overline{B} = \overline{A \setminus B}$.

Tags: general-topology

Let $(X,\tau)$ be a topological space, and $A,B \subset X$. I am asked to prove or disprove that $\overline{A}\setminus \overline{B} = \overline{A \setminus B}$. I know that in general, $\overline{A \setminus B}\not\subset \overline{A}\setminus \overline{B}$. Two easy examples that I can think are if $\tau$ is the indiscrete topology, so that the $X \not\subset \varnothing$ if $X \neq \varnothing$, and in the real line $(\Bbb R, \tau_{\Bbb R})$, taking $A = \Bbb R$ and $B = \Bbb Q$.

I think that the inclusion $\overline{A}\setminus\overline{B} \subset \overline{A\setminus B}$ is true in general, but I don't know how to go at this, and I can't find counter-examples.

Hints?

Comment: For me, the trouble is in showing every open neighborhood $U$ of $x$ intersects $B^{c}$ (where $x \in \overline{A} - \overline{B}$).  If we could prove that, we would be done.  It's easy to see that there is some open neighborhood of $x$ that is contained in $B^{c}$, but does that imply every open neighborhood of $x$ intersects $B^{c}$?

Comment: If $x \in \overline{A}\setminus\overline{B}$, for all $V \in \mathscr{V}_x$ we have $V \cap A \neq \varnothing$, and exists a special neighbourhood $V_\ast \in \mathscr{V}_x$ such that $V_\ast \cap B = \varnothing$. Just using the definition here. If we proved that $V \cap (A \setminus B) \neq \varnothing$ we're done, but I don't know how to throw $V_\ast$ into the mix..

Comment: Yes, we said the same in different terms... `:(`

Comment: Check my answer!  Please let me know if there are any mistakes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x \in \overline{A} - \overline{B}$.  We will show $x \in \overline{A - B}$.  This amounts to showing for every open $U$ with $x \in U$, $U \cap (A - B) \neq \emptyset$.

Note that $A - B = A \cap B^{c}$.

Let $U$ be open with $x \in U$.

Since $x \in \overline{A}$, $U \cap A \neq \emptyset$.

Now, $x \not \in \overline{B}$ which means there is some open $V$ such that $x \in V$ and $V \subseteq B^{c}$.  But $B^{c} \subseteq \overline{B^{c}}$ which means $x \in \overline{B^{c}}$.  This implies $U \cap B^{c} \neq \emptyset$.

So, we showed for every open $U$ with $x \in U$, $U \cap (A \cap B^{c}) \neq \emptyset$, which implies $x \in \overline{A \cap B^{c}} = \overline{A - B}$.

Comment: I win?? I win!!

Comment: Hey, thanks! This seems to work nicely!

Comment: There's no flaw in the argument. The implications are all clear. Yes, you win haha